# how to parse text

Tags: python, file, string

i have a question that i want to read a file, search for any line that has session ID (e.i. 12345), if matched then print all lines after that until encounter newline.
after that, how can i associate all these lines to the session ID if i need to further parse these lines.
And i want to do it in Python.

Thanks

Comment: `print all lines after that until encounter newline` - looks like it is gonna be only 1 line. Be more specific please. Your question is too general.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward to write, but the particulars will be dominated by your file format -- what is that?  Also, "print all lines .. until encounter newline" doesn't make sense, as all lines will end with a newline.  What did you really mean?

Comment: A little off topic, but how did you get this userid. "user589837"

Answer (score 3):

this answers the first part of your question:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '12456' in line:
            print line
```

I didn't understand what else you were asking for.  can you translate : "how can i associate all these lines to the session ID if i need to further parse these lines"?

Comment: thanks Corey. I think i'm not clear in my question. my file will contain likes with number like 123456 and followed by other lines like a:123\nb:234\n and newline. i want to if found 123456, then print all lines after that until hitting blank line and 123456 will happy many times in the file, so i want to print all the time that session 123456 happens with all lines after that.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that your log file is formatted like

```
session 321: abc de
    567 89 abd ec

session 12345: ghi lm
    763 98 dba ce
```

and that what you want to do is find the appropriate session and all following lines until you see a blank line.

```
import collections
import re

sessionData = collections.defaultdict(list)
lookfor = [12345, 13981]
newSession = re.compile(r'session (\d+):')

with open('my_log_file.txt', 'r') as inf:
    session = None
    for ln in inf:
        ln = ln.rstrip()
        if len(ln):
            match = newSession.match(ln)
            if match:
                s = int(match.group(0))
                if s in lookfor:
                    session = s
            if session:
                print ln
                sessionData[session].append(ln)
        else:
            session = None
```

sessionData is now a session-keyed dict; for each session, it contains a list of all related lines. Using the above sample data, sessionData would look like

```
{ 12345: ["session 12345: ghi lm", "    763 98 dba ce"] }
```

Comment: thanks Hugh. If there're many lines with same session ID like 12345. Is it gonna display all the lines or only just 1st time. i want to display all lines with that session ID because that session ID line will appear many times with different timestamp in the file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user589837: it will collect all of them, appending them to the list referenced by sessionData[sessionID].